# loop in excel without using VBA or macros

Tags: excel, loops, excel-formula

I have a table in Excel where I have categories and money like so:

[image]

I want to calculate the sum of all A category and B And C.
So I have to put a rule like this for the cell B1

```
=if(cell next B1 witch is A1="a";get B1)
```

and do the same for all other cells in B row.

How can I get the total of money collected from category A  and from category B?

Comment: Look up Pivot Tables.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [`SUMIFS` function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx). For example, in E2 you might put

```
=sumifs(b$2:b$19, a$2:a$19, d2)
```

Comment: sumifs may be overkill because the OP only has a single criteria.  Plus that function is only available in Excel 2007 and greater.

Comment: @sous2817 True, but I tend to prefer it over SUMIF for maintainability reasons: if I need to add more conditions later, and it's a SUMIF, I have to re-order the parameters to convert it to SUMIFS.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly: in cell E2 use the following formula:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$19,D2,$B$2:$B19)
```

and copy down.  Change the ranges to suit your situation.

Answer (score 0):

use SumIf this checks Col A for the character "a" and adds up the value in B

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"a",B:B)
```